# Stop scrolling in a listview when user touches the list - android

Tags: android, android-listview, scroll

I have a list view that contains about 30 items. When I scroll it down it just goes to the very bottom of the list and does not stop when the user touches the list.

Is there a method to stop the scrolling when the list view is touched and at the same time user should be able to navigate using onItemClick(already handled)..

Thank you!

Comment: That's the default behaviour... did you customize Android in any way?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Use [`smoothScrollBy`](https://developer.android.com/reference/android/widget/AbsListView#smoothScrollBy(int,%20int)).

```
@Override 
public boolean onTouchEvent(MotionEvent ev) 
{ 
    switch (ev.getAction()) 
    {
        case MotionEvent.ACTION_UP:
            this.smoothScrollBy(0, 0); 
            break; 
    } 
    return super.onTouchEvent(ev);
}
```

Answer (score 0):

By referring to Nitin Gupta's answer, I came up with my own:

```
public class OnTouchListenr implements OnTouchListener{

    @Override
    public boolean onTouch(View v, MotionEvent event) {
        if(event.getAction()==MotionEvent.ACTION_DOWN)  
        {
            businessResultListView.smoothScrollBy(0, 0); 
            return true;
        }

        return false;
    }          
}
```

Then I set the OnTouchListener on the list view like this:

```
businessResultListView.setOnTouchListener(new OnTouchListenr());
```

Answer (score 0):

Override **dispatchTouchEvent** in your Listview

```
@Override
public boolean dispatchTouchEvent(MotionEvent ev){
   if(ev.getAction()==MotionEvent.ACTION_MOVE){
      return true;
   }return super.dispatchTouchEvent(ev);
}
```